# Vector Algebra - Parallelogram question.

Tags: geometry, vectors

> ABCD is a parallelogram. E is on AD such that AE : ED = 1 : n - 1. BE meets the diagonal AC at P. If AP : AC = 1 : x, show that AB + nAE = xAP.

[image]

I proved it this way:

$$\frac{AP}{AC}=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$AC=xAP$$

and

$$\frac{AE}{ED}=\frac{1}{n-1}$$
$$ED=(n-1)AD$$

We know
$$AD=AE+ED$$
$$AD=AE+(n-1)AE$$
$$AD=nAE$$

We can see that:
$$AB=AC-DA$$
$$AB=xAP-nAE$$
Therefore,
$$AB+nAE=xAP$$

It is the second part of the question that puzzles me a little:

> Hence show that BE divides AC in the ratio of 1 : n

I am unable to see how I can use the previous result to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$BE$ divides $AC$ in ratio $\frac{AP}{PC}$

since $\frac{AP}{AC}=\frac{1}{x}$, So $\frac{AP}{PC}=\frac{1}{x-1}$

Now we need to show that $x-1=n$

From your equation
$$AB+nAE=xAP$$
Since three points $B,P$ and $E$ are collinear, sum of coefficients of $AB,AE,AP$ is equal to $0$ (see below for proof)

$\therefore 1+n-x=0$ so we showed that $x-1=n$

---

**Proof:**

Since $B,P,E$ are collinear

$$BP=\lambda PE$$

By triangle law $BP=AP-AB$ and $PE=AE-AP$, put it in above equation.

$$(AP-AB)=\lambda (AE-AP)$$
$$(\lambda)AE + (-1-\lambda)AP + (1)AB = 0$$

So you can notice that sum of coefficients is zero